# How to animate individual items of a Sliver List

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make a Sliver list whose elements are rotated at 90' at first but when tapped they rotate back to 0' and vice verse. The animation itself is working fine but the problem is the scroll only work when the items are at 0'.
Can someone please tell me how can I fix this?

I tried wrapping a container around the list item and observed that the sliver only accounts for the item at 0' but not the item at 90'. I even tried changing the height of the container itself but it gives weird results.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  Animation<double> animation;
  Animation<double> animationOffset;
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 2));

    animation = Tween<double>(begin: -Math.pi / 2, end: 0).animate(controller)
    ..addStatusListener((status){
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed){
        controller.reverse();
      }else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed){
        controller.forward();
      }
    });

    animationOffset = Tween<double>(begin: 87, end: 0).animate(controller)
    ..addStatusListener(
        (status){
          print('$status');
          print('value: ${animationOffset.value}');
        }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => GestureDetector(
    child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverPadding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          sliver: SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                  Container(color: Colors.green, child: AnimatedBuilder(animation: animationOffset, builder:(context, child) => Transform.translate(offset: Offset(0, 0),child: RotateTransition(child: TextWidget(), animation: animation)))),
              ]),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    onTap: () {
      if(animation.status == AnimationStatus.completed){
        controller.reverse();
      }
      else if (animation.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed){
        controller.forward();
      } 
    },
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I tried using `SliverAnimatedOpacity()` for animating opacity and it worked fine. Hope it helps someone